# [disabled]: Change the value of a property by another component

Tags: angular, typescript

My button should be disabled, whenever the property `callToActionBtn` is true.

**match-component.html**

```html
<button [disabled]="callToActionBtn" (click)="sendTask()>Send</button>
```

**match-component.ts**

```js
public callToActionBtn = false;
private sendTask() {
  this.matchResult.sendEmailToMatchPerson(this.finalFormValues).subscribe(data => {
    if (data === 1) {
      this.callToActionBtn = true;
    }
  });
}
```

So far, everything works great! But my problem is that I have another component and that should set the property back to `false`.

**form.component.ts**

```js
constructor(private matchComponent: MatchComponent) {}
// ... whenever the form has been submitted,
this.matchComponent.callToActionBtn = false;
console.log(this.matchComponent.callToActionBtn); // returns false
```

Even though the component *form* sets the property to `false`, my button is still disabled. Why?

Comment: Try to use ViewChild: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: How your components are placed? Is there any parent child relationship between form component and match component? Please share example

Comment: show structutre or sample stackblitz link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't edit component property within other components.
Create a dedicated service:

```
class ExampleService {
  callToActionBtnSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  setCall(value: boolean): void {
    this.callToActionBtnSubject.next(value);
  }
  getCall(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.callToActionBtnSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

In match-component, use the service and subscribes to the subject.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.exampleService.getCall().subscribe((boolean) => { this.callToActionBtn = boolean; }
}
```

Changes the subject value instead component property value, it will be updated anyway in subscribes block.

```
if (data === 1) {
  this.exampleService.setCall(true);
}
```

In form component, subscribes to the subject like in the match-component.
If you want to change value within form component, same as match-component:

```
this.exampleService.setCall(true) // or false
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, calling methods are not clear but you can have a look at below link, it might help you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxeyzr

One more thing: you need to tell your structure for proper code as in Angular for communication variaous methods like **viewChild**, **ViewChildren** etc are being used.